# For loop only inserting first character of data into db

Tags: php, mysql

I have this frustrating problem, i am using a for loop to insert data into a database, the data is inserting into the DB, but it is only inserting the first character, for example instead of inserting the word example, it will only insert the letter e. 
See screenprint below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMOXL.png)
*The top row is a example row*

This is my first time using a for loop, so i was wondering if it something i have missed out in my code, which is causing this problem.

**Code**

```
$_query = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < count($OI); $x++) {

$_query = "INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name,
Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) 
VALUES ('" . $OI[$x] . "', '" . $ip[$x] . "','" . $_SESSION['rest_id'][$x] . "','" . $rest_name[$x] . "',
        '" . $City_name[$x] . "','" . $Product_Id[$x] . "','" . $product_name[$x] . "','" . $prod_price[$x] . "','" . $item_sub[$x] . "')";

            }
            $query_run = $dbc->prepare($_query);
            echo $_query;

            if (!$query_run->execute()) {
                $insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $query_run->error;
                print "affected rows:" . $query_run->affected_rows; //how many records affected?         
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the column name?

Comment: and give me a var_dump of `$ip`

Comment: @user6456767: Why are you making `$_query` an array on line 1 and then turning around and making it a string on line 5? Furthermore, what is `$OI`?

Comment: What are fields types ?

Comment: Which column is only getting one character? `Resturant_ID` is my (one) guess...

Comment: @JefréN. all the columns are only getting one character for example the ip on local host is :1 or :2 but it is only showing :

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name,
Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub and the var dump is "::1"

Comment: @Splash int , decimals and varcahar

Comment: @user6456767: Please give me the output of  `gettype($City_name);`

Comment: so it's the value of "custmer_ip"?

Comment: @JefréN. sorry about the delay have been at work. "Enfield" but that can change depending on the restaurant which is visited

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim sorry about the delay I've been at work it is ::1, which is my localhost ip address

Comment: Wondering why this has been marked as a duplicate, when they are two different questions

Comment: @user6456767: So is $City_name a custom object or something? "Enfield" is not in the list of types `gettype()` will return according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php). Could you give me a `var_dump($City_name);`, please?

Comment: Var_dump $city_name prints out "Enfield". No it is selected from another query and made into a local variable

Comment: Is that all it tells you? Is the column type of the query it comes from 'enum'? Are you positive the '[$x]' is necessary for everything?

Comment: @JefréN. yeah, that is exactly what it prints out. The column is varchar(100). I was sure [$x] was needed but after checking my db, it doesn't them to be doing what i expected it to do

Comment: What is $OI? Or, more specifically, what do you get with an `echo count($OI);` What do you get with an `echo $City_name;`? Why are you using brackets when `$City_name` is not an array?

Comment: @JefréN. $OI is the order id, which is auto incremented in another table. Every order has its own id. It was a area "$_query_parts  = array();"

Comment: What about the other questions? (Not trying to try your patience, I'm just trying to help... and I need more information. :D)

Comment: @user6456767: Did you get my last question? ...

Comment: @user6456767: Did you figure it out? Can I un-favorite this question?

Comment: I hope you solve your problem... :)